# Figuring out average transaction duration with separate MYSQL rows for start and end?

Tags: mysql

Given the table format below, where there is a separate row for the user clicking and completing a given event that share an `event_id` in common, it is possible to determine the average difference in time between click and complete in a single query?

```
id      event_id      event_type      event_create_date

1        11            click          2014-01-01 00:00:01
2        12            click          2014-01-01 00:00:02 
3        11            complete       2014-01-01 00:01:01
4        13            click          2014-01-01 00:02:01
5        12            complete       2014-01-01 00:03:01
```

Comment: What's the output you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELF JOIN` and using TIMESTAMPDIFF, average can be calculated.

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,T2.event_create_date - T1.event_create_date))
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table1 T2
ON T1.event_type ='click'
and T2.event_type ='complete'
and T1.event_id = T2.event_id
```